# A rank reduction theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a matrix and let $W$ be a matrix of the form
$W =
\begin{bmatrix}
M & 0 \\
AB & AA^T
\end{bmatrix}
\in \mathbb{R}^{(m+n) \times (k+n)}$ for some matrices $M \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$. Then, regardless of what $B$ is, we always have

> $rank(M) = rank(W) - rank(A)$

How do I prove this?

Comment: I encountered this theorem in the book _An Invitation to 3-D Vision: From Images to Geometric Models_ by Jana Kosecka and Yi Ma (Appendix A, Lemma A.26). It's used for proving rank conditions of multiview matrices.

Comment: *Hint* : $rk(AA^T) = rk(A)$

Comment: Try to prove that the rank of $W$ is the sum of the ranks of its diagonal entries using the definition of rank as the maximum number of linearly independent column/row vectors.

Comment: @StubbornAtom that is not true a priori for block upper-triangular matrices.  For example,
$$
\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}
$$
does not have rank $0$, as your comment seems to suggest.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, I rather meant to say $\mathrm{rank}\left[\begin{matrix}A_{11} & O \\A_{21} & A_{22} \\\end{matrix}\right]\ge\mathrm{rank}(A_{11})+\mathrm{rank}(A_{22})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, note that $rk(AA^T) = rk(A)$. By counting linearly independent columns, we see that
$$
rk(W) \geq rk(M) + rk(AA^T) = rk(M) + rk(A)
$$
That is, if certain columns of $M$ and $AA^T$ are linearly independent, then the corresponding columns are linearly independent in $W$, which means that we have *at least* that many linearly independent columns in $W$ all together (we could have used rows here in the same way).

On the other hand, by counting linearly independent rows, we have
$$
rk(W) \leq rk \pmatrix{M&0} + rk\pmatrix{AB & AA^T} = 
rk(M) + rk\pmatrix{AB & AA^T}
$$
However, note that
$$
rk\pmatrix{AB & AA^T} = rk[A\pmatrix{B & A^T}] \leq rk(A)
$$
So, we have
$$
rk(W) \leq rk (M) + rk(A)
$$
With these two inequalities, we have
$$
rk(W) = rk(M) + rk(A)
$$
which was the desired conclusion.

Comment: How do you get the first inequality, i.e. $rk(W) \geq rk(M) + rk(AA^T)$?

Comment: I attempt to explain exactly that in the column below.

Comment: I still don't understand. How can we establish this relationship without taking the off-diagonal submatrices into account? Does the submatrix in the first row and the second column being $0$ help in any way?

Comment: It seems to me like you're not reading the words: *if certain columns of $M$ and $AA^T$ are linearly independent, then the corresponding columns are linearly independent in $W$*. I am fully taking advantage of the zero in the upper-right corner.  Should I further elaborate on that?

Comment: The zero in the upper right corner comes into play in proving that the columns in $M$ and $AA^T$ which are linearly independent in the respective matrices are also linearly independent when considered together as columns of $W$. Am I right?

Comment: @niranjantdesai that's exactly it.